# How Can I Make Python Read Only a Certain Part Off A Site

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, roblox

```py
@bot.command()
async def id2r(ctx, id):
   response = requests.get(f'https://verify.eryn.io/api/user/{id}')
   
   id2r = discord.Embed(
       title='***Discord ID Scan ↴***', color=16, description=f'{response.text}')
   id2r.timestamp = datetime.now()
   await ctx.send(embed=id2r)
```

[image]

I want it to only print `robloxUsername` and not print the full output given by the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called `json` format usually the api result use it.

`.json()` To make it Json instead of raw text.

Then call it like this `response['robloxUsername']`

```py
@bot.command()
async def id2r(ctx, id):
    response = requests.get(f'https://verify.eryn.io/api/user/{id}').json()

    id2r = discord.Embed(
        title='***Discord ID Scan ↴***', color=16, description=response["robloxUsername"])
    id2r.timestamp = datetime.now()
    await ctx.send(embed=id2r)
```

P.S: I would suggest using the status since if the id is wrong the wanted field will not be there.